# How to change colors of kendo panelbar at each level on the basis of range validation using jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

```
          <div>
 @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("LeaderPanelbar")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
    .Items(panelbar =>
    {
        foreach (var r in Model)
        {
            float PassKey = r.PassKey;
            panelbar.Add().Text(Convert.ToString(r.PassKey))
                .Expanded(true)
                .Content(@<div style="padding: 10px;">
           @Html.Action("PanelItemContent", new { Key = PassKey, sDateRange = ViewBag.SelectedDateRange, sListText = ViewBag.ListText, sCustomEndDate = ViewBag.CustomEndDate, sWidgetTitle = ViewBag.WidgetTitle, sWidgetType = ViewBag.WidgetType, HygieneDelay = ViewBag.HygieneDelay, GracePeriod = ViewBag.GracePeriod, RGracePeriod = ViewBag.RGracePeriod })

        </div>);
        }

    })
)
 </div>
```

then i have to add conditions in the panelbar to show different colors at each level.

Answer (score 0):

I would move that logic into your Model not jQuery and make your Model a little more complex.  It looks like you model is just a List at the moment.

```
// Model
public class Leader
{
    public float PassKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompare { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBaseline { get; set; }
    // Not sure what you are
    public string StatusColor
    {
        get {
            // do your logic on the dates?
            return "red" // Ex.
        }
    }
}

// Controller
public ActionResult LeaderPage()
{
    var model = new IList<Leader>();
    model.Add(new Leader {PassKey = "???", DateCompare = [YourDate], DateBaseLine = [AnotherDate]})
    // Add more (programatically)

    return View(model);
}

// View
for each (Leader leader in Model)
    float PassKey = leader.PassKey;
...
    .Content(@<div style="padding: 10px; color: @leader.StatusColor;">
...
```

Or something like that, just typing off the top of my head.  When you can I think it is better to try to make your data smarter, rather than your UI smarter.

I hope this helps.